# JFrame not displaying anything

Tags: java, swing

I cannot seem to get a rectangle to be displayed in the JFrame. Per the parameters of this project, I have to have this class implement the Icon interface. When I run the code as is, I get the JFrame, but nothing shows up inside. It should display a black square. I'm assuming the problem has something to do with how I am initializing the graphics instance variable. I don't have much experience working with GUI graphics, so I'm not entirely clear on how to do this correctly.

And yes, I do know that the getIconWidth and getIconHeight methods are redundant since I am using constants, but I have to have these methods in order to implement the interface.

```
public class MugDisplay extends JFrame implements Icon {
private int width;
private int height;
private JPanel panel;
private Graphics graphics;

private static final int ICON_WIDTH = 100;
private static final int ICON_HEIGHT = 100;


public MugDisplay() {
    this.configureGui();
    this.panel = new JPanel();
    this.panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(this.panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.graphics = this.getGraphics();
    int xPos = (this.panel.getWidth() - this.getIconWidth()) / 2;
    int yPos = (this.panel.getHeight() - this.getIconHeight()) / 2;
    this.paintIcon(this.panel, this.graphics, xPos, yPos);
}


@Override
public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fillRect(x, y, ICON_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT);
}


@Override
public int getIconWidth() {
    return ICON_WIDTH;
}


@Override
public int getIconHeight() {
    return ICON_HEIGHT;
}

private void configureGui() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

In the interest of having a MCVE, here is the driver class that calls this class.

```
 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MugDisplay md = new MugDisplay();
    md.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: Don't use `this.getGraphics();` to get the graphics and don't call `paintIcon` in the constructor. Override the `paint` method of the frame, call `super.paint(g)`, calculate x & y and call `paintIcon` inside there (parsing the graphics instance of the paint method). You might also want to consider switching to a `JPanel` and override `paintComponent` instead, as I don't really see what the benefit of overriding `paint` of the frame in this case is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.graphics = this.getGraphics()` is not how custom painting works in Swing. What you should do is create a panel, override its `paintComponent` method, make the call to `super`, and *then* do your painting. For instance:

```
panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int xPos = ...
        paintIcon(this, g, xPos, yPos);
    }
}
```

Calling `getGraphics` will provide you with a short-lived `Graphics` object that can soon become invalid, which is why you should opt for overriding `paintComponent` instead, which will always give you a usable `Graphics` object. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

On a separate note, it looks like you're calling `setVisible(true)` before you're finished adding the necessary components to the JFrame. To ensure that your components show up, call `setVisible(true)` after adding them all to the frame.

Comment: Thank you. That resolved my issue. I didn't even know you could declare a panel with that syntax.